# Why do I get an error of cycling inheritance involving MyFragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, inheritance, callback

I am trying to send data from activity to fragment and vice versa using interfaces but getting an error of cycling inheritance involving MyFragment.

Implementing interface created in MyFragment:

```
public class MyActivity implements OnSendFromMyFragListener {
  OnSendFromMyActivityListener mCallback;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      mCallback.sendFromMyActivity(2);
  }

  @Override
  public void sendFromMyFrag (int a) {
    //do something
  }

  public interface OnSendFromMyActivityListener {
    public void sendFromMyActivity(int b);
  }
}
```

Implementing interface created in MyActivity:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements OnSendFromMyActivityListener {
  OnSendFromMyFragListener mCallback;

  public interface OnSendFromMyFragListener {
      void sendFromMyFrag(int a);
  }
  @Override
  public void onAttach(Context context) {
      super.onAttach(context);
      try {
          mCallback = (OnSendFromMyFragListener) context;
      } catch (ClassCastException e) {
          throw new ClassCastException(context.toString());
      }
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  }

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my, container, false);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    mCallback.sendFromMyFrag(1);
                }
            }
        });
    return view;
  }

  @Override
  public void sendFromMyActivity(int b) {
    //do something
  }
}
```

Comment: why your callback variable is different from interface that you have impplemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the reason you are getting this error is because your `Activity` depends on your `Fragment` and `Fragment` depends on your `Activity`. Don't Agree?

Let me show you. Imagine you are a compiler in your work you stumbled across:

```
class A implements B.A {
    interface B {
        void foo1();
    }

    @Override
    public void foo2()
    {
        // do something;
    }
}
```

Now you know that `class A` depends on (implements) `B.A`, so before you go further into `class A` you move on to `class B`:

```
class B implements A.B {
    interface A {
        void foo2();
    }

    @Override
    public void foo1()
    {
        // Do Something;
    }
}
```

Now you see that `class B` depends on (implements) `class A` specifically `class A.B`! What do you (compiler) do? Go back to `class A`? But that depends on `class B`. So you see this becomes an unending cycle thus causing a cyclic dependency where both your class' definitions depend on each other.

As an alternative you could either create a member event listener or an anonymous one. Or if you don't like either of those options, you could also create a separate java interface class file for any one of the two interfaces.

Comment: Yeah, creating a separate interface file works fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to do this for Activity

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyFragment.OnSendFromMyFragListener {


public interface OnSendFromMyActivityListener {
    void sendFromMyActivity(int b);
}

OnSendFromMyActivityListener mCallback;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    MyFragment myFragment = MyFragment.newInstance();
    //Do the transaction.....
    //And after this

    mCallback.sendFromMyActivity(0);

}

public void setOnSendFromMyActivityListener(OnSendFromMyActivityListener mCallback){
    this.mCallback = mCallback;
}

@Override
public void sendFromMyFrag(int a) {
    //do something
}}
```

And this for Fragment

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements OnSendFromMyActivityListener {
OnSendFromMyFragListener mCallback;

public interface OnSendFromMyFragListener {
    void sendFromMyFrag(int a);
}

public static MyFragment newInstance() {

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    try {
        mCallback = (OnSendFromMyFragListener) getActivity();
        ((MyActivity) getActivity()).setOnSendFromMyActivityListener(this);
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(context.toString());
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_place_suggest, container, false);

    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mCallback.sendFromMyFrag(1);
        }
    });

return view;
}

@Override
public void sendFromMyActivity(int b) {
    //do something
}
```

if you want you can put setters of the interface also to the Fragment for better abstraction.
Something you have to watch out is to look for nulls interfaces
Thanks